# How to subset variable names in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
head(data)
                              country      fixef
1             as.factor(country.x)Albania -0.4446439
2             as.factor(country.x)Algeria -0.3400060
3             as.factor(country.x)Andorra -1.0455948
4              as.factor(country.x)Angola  0.7477114
5 as.factor(country.x)Antigua and Barbuda -0.1996655
6           as.factor(country.x)Argentina -0.3404206
```

How can I remove (in R) everything else besides the name of the country, so that it would look like this:

```
head(data)
                     country      fixef
1                    Albania -0.4446439
2                    Algeria -0.3400060
3                    Andorra -1.0455948
4                    Angola   0.7477114
5        Antigua and Barbuda -0.1996655
6                  Argentina -0.3404206
```

Thank you,

Antonio Pedro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the answer that was posted a few minutes ago (but seems to have been withdrawn) best to just not create that problem in the first place! But if you want to correct what you already have, look up `?gsub` and try something like:

```
data$country <- gsub("as\\.factor\\(country\\.x\\)", "", data$country)
```

Comment: Also, the `fixed` option seems well suited for this case: `gsub("as.factor(country.x)", "", data$country, fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

```
data$country <- with(data, {
    country <- as.character(country)
    factor(substr(country, 21, nchar(country)))
})
```